# Trying to optimize the code using @tailrec but failing

Tags: scala, code-generation, tail-recursion

I want to use `@tailrec` in Scala to convert the code to tail recursive but I get an error saying the function is not in the tail position but I disagree with the conclusion of the compiler. I appreciate any help or hint.

```
  @tailrec
  def f_index_scope(v_sc : T_ContextPtr, v_i : Int):T_ContextPtr = {
    var  v1_result : T_ContextPtr = null.asInstanceOf[T_ContextPtr];
    if (v_or(new M__basic_2[ T_ContextPtr](t_ContextPtr).v__op_0(v_sc,new M__basic_8[ T_ContextPtr](t_ContextPtr).v_nil),new M__basic_2[ T_Integer](t_Integer).v__op_0(v_i,0))) {
      v1_result = v_sc;
    } else {
      val node = v_sc;
      node match {
        case p_context(_,v_0) => {
          return f_index_scope(a_ptr.get(v_sc),new M__basic_4[ T_Integer](t_Integer).v__op_u(v_i,1));
        }
        case _ => {
        }}
    }
    return v1_result;
  }
```

> Could not optimize @tailrec annotated method f_index_scope: it contains a recursive call not in tail position

[Minimal example repository](https://github.com/amir734jj/scala-tailrec-issue/tree/c35317aa385e99643feeb660c7b31b605b65b206)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `return` in Scala

```
@tailrec
final /*private*/ def f_index_scope(v_sc: T_ContextPtr, v_i: T_Integer): T_ContextPtr = {
  if (v_or(new M__basic_2[T_ContextPtr](t_ContextPtr).v__op_0(v_sc, new M__basic_8[T_ContextPtr](t_ContextPtr).v_nil), new M__basic_2[T_Integer](t_Integer).v__op_0(v_i, 0))) {
    v_sc
  } else {
    v_sc match {
      case p_context(_, _) =>
        f_index_scope(a_ptr.get(v_sc), new M__basic_4[T_Integer](t_Integer).v__op_u(v_i, 1))
      case _ =>
        null
    }
  }
}
```

Scala is expression-oriented. The last expression in a block is its value (the value returned by block/method).

If the method is not final or private then it complains: `could not optimize @tailrec annotated method f_index_scope: it is neither private nor final so can be overridden`.

https://github.com/amir734jj/scala-tailrec-issue/pull/1

Comment: I'm genuinely wondering what made OP think that their function was tail recursive, it's like a ball of spaghetti and only one single code branch behind one `if` and one `case` ends up in a recursive call. Good job untangling it

Comment: @slouc because it's a code-generated code. Not hand generated.

Comment: Oh okay. But I didn't mean to take a poke at the code itself, I was just wondering what made you think that it would be tail recursive, because there's three paths and only one resolves in a call. Even @Dmytro's solution smells a bit because of `case _ => null` but oh well

Comment: @slouc I didn't want to dig deeper whether this null is used outside sometimes.

Comment: Yeah I figured :) still, great job. I was gonna write an answer using hypothetical mini examples but you did it better

Comment: My understanding is that the code is generated by https://github.com/boyland/aps https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1996/CSD-96-916.pdf